# Macro runs on one computer and get run time error 5 on anothe

Tags: macros, runtime

I run a macro on one computer and it is fine
And on another it gives me the run time error 5: invalid procedure call or argument

This is the code he doesn`t like:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(R, C)), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:="ProjectsOW!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion _
:=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

- CAUSE

This problem occurs because the destination worksheet and the range for the new PivotTable are specified in the recorded macro. Therefore, the recorded macro is not dynamic. Additionally, the recorded macro cannot be played repeatedly.

- RESOLUTION

To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

1. In the Microsoft Visual Basic Editor (VBE), locate the code for the recorded macro.
2. Empty the value of the TableDestination variable as in the following example.

   TableDestination=""
3. On the File menu, click Save.

   - STATUS

Microsoft has confirmed that this is a problem in the Microsoft products that are listed in the "Applies to" section.

[For more info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/940166)

Comment: Hi!Thank you for your answer

Comment: Hi..this is not really my case, since I need my sheets to be named by specific names...